# Numpy restoration of state using default_rng instead of RandomState

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

This is how I am current restoring the state of a random generator incase my script gets stopped in the middle by accident. So in order to continue, the script I save the state of the random state and load it when I need it to generate samples from where it left off.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import RandomState

rndgen = RandomState(42)

i1 = rndgen.random_integers(low=0, high=1, size=10)
print(i1)

A = np.array(rndgen.get_state(), dtype=object)

np.save('saved_state.npy', A)

i2 = rndgen.random_integers(low=0, high=1, size=10)
print(i2)

ar = np.load('saved_state.npy', allow_pickle=True)
B = rndgen.set_state(tuple(ar))

print(rndgen.random_integers(low=0, high=1, size=10))
```

**How do I implement this same functionality but with default_rng()? instead of RandomState? Is it even possible?**

Output:

> [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1] # 1st generation of numbers

> [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0] # 2nd generation of numbers

> [0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0] # Same 2nd sequence of numbers generated after loading the state

Comment: Did you try to save the Generator that is returned by [`default_rng()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.default_rng)? If you're lucky that already works. Otherwise it seems you can access the state similarly with `default_rng().bit_generator.state`. See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#accessing-the-bitgenerator) and [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/pcg64.html#state)

Comment: Yes I tried replacing RandomState() with default_rng() but that didn't do the trick. However, your method has worked. Thank you. If you post your comment as an Answer, I will mark it solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, this is what I did based on [André](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7672162/andr%C3%A9)'s comment:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
from numpy.random import default_rng

rndgen = default_rng(42)
print(rndgen.integers(low=0, high=1, size=10, endpoint=True))

S = rndgen.bit_generator.state
with open('saved_state.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(S, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

print(rndgen.integers(low=0, high=1, size=10, endpoint=True))

with open('saved_state.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    rndgen.bit_generator.state = pickle.load(handle)

print(rndgen.integers(low=0, high=1, size=10, endpoint=True))
```

The output as required is:

> [0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]

> [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]

> [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]